# Google Image Mobile SlideShow

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

Do you have any ideas on the implementation of the image slideshow on Google Image for iPhone ?
They use the slide animation, you can swipe using your fingers. It's really well done.

[image: SlideShow for image results on Google Images for iPhone]

Comment: http://www.jaipho.com/ is doing something like that but I find it very hard to install and use.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into this, this seems to be the simplest implementation that works on Android and iPhone.

https://github.com/zgrossbart/jstouchslide